# Can I inject a seam component into a enum?

Tags: java, enums

I'm using SEAM 2.2.2 and I've defined several enums for managing my types, but I have the doubt.

Can I inject a seam component into a enum ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afraid not as they can't be instantiated. Use a factory if you're backing a dropdown in the UI:

https://community.jboss.org/message/480770